# No syntax errors, but program does not produce any results

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods

I have to create a program for class. My applications needs to have value returning methods for `OilLubeCharges()`, `FlushCharges()`, `MiscCharges()`, `OtherCharges()`, `TaxCharges()`, `TotalCharges()`.

It needs to have void methods for `ClearOilLube()`, `ClearFlushes()`, `ClearMisc()`, `ClearOther()`, `ClearFees()`.

Currently my code has no syntax errors, however when I compile it it does not calculate anything. The calculate, clear, and exit buttons also do not work. Any assistance as to why these issues are occurring would be appreciated. Below is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OilLubeCharges();
        FlushCharges();
        MiscCharges();
        OtherCharges();
        TaxCharges();
        TotalCharges();
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oilCheckBox.Checked = false;
        lubeCheckBox.Checked = false;
        radFlushBox.Checked = false;
        tranFlushBox.Checked = false;
        insCheckBox.Checked = false;
        mufCheckBox.Checked = false;
        tireCheckBox.Checked = false;
        partsTextBox.Text = "";
        laborTextBox.Text = "";
        serLabTotalTextBox.Text = "";
        partsTotalTextBox.Text = "";
        taxPartsTextBox.Text = "";
        totalFeesTextBox.Text = "";
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private int OilLubeCharges()
    {
        int total = 0;

        if (oilCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 26;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }

        if (lubeCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 18;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }
    }

    private int FlushCharges()
    {
        int total = 0;

        if (radFlushBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 30;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }

        if (tranFlushBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 80;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }
    }

    private int MiscCharges()
    {
        int total = 0;

        if (insCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 15;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }

        if (mufCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 100;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }

        if (tireCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            total += 20;
            serLabTotalTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }
    }

    private int OtherCharges()
    {
        int total = 0;
        int parts = 0;
        int labor = 0;

        if (int.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out parts))
        {
            partsTextBox.Text = parts.ToString("c");
            total = parts;
        }

        if (int.TryParse(laborTextBox.Text, out labor))
        {
            laborTextBox.Text = labor.ToString("c");
            return total;
        }
        else
        {
            return total;
        }
    }

    private decimal TaxCharges()
    {
        decimal parts = 0;
        decimal partsTax;

        partsTax = parts * .06m;
        taxPartsTextBox.Text = partsTax.ToString("c");
        return partsTax;
    }

    private decimal TotalCharges()
    {
        decimal total = 0;

        total = OilLubeCharges() + FlushCharges() + MiscCharges() + TaxCharges() + OtherCharges();
        totalFeesTextBox.Text = total.ToString("c");
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make sure that the Calculate, Clear and Exit button event methods (CalcButton_Click, ClearButton_Click, ExitButton_Click) are correctly hooked up to the corresponding click events on the buttons on your UI. If they are, putting breakpoints in the events will help you debug what is actually happening.

Comment: Debug the code by adding break points (F9) and step through the code (F11).  You probably aren't reaching all the code and we cannot help without more info.

Comment: Try verifying the events are called using Breakpoints or a good old `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Where should I place these? I have tried a few different times and a window pops up but nothing happens.

Comment: @Eysaak You put it in any function or execution fork you are not sure off that it is called. For as long as you need to verify it works. Kinda like how you would put a Console.WirteLine() for debug output.

Comment: You need to learn about how to use the debugger !! - In fact nobody should come here and ask a question unless he has used the debugger to find out the most basic things, like is the code reached.. - Btw: Do not use Messagebox for debugging as it will often hide issues, esp. witjh timing and/or inputs rather than bringing them out!

Comment: Particular "The calculate, clear, and exit buttons also do not work" indicates the event is not registered on the designer side.

Comment: A common cause is that you didn't create the events yourself (e.g. by double-clicking the buttons or the event name in the event paneö) but simply copied somebody else's code..?

Comment: @TaW: I did only say to check if a function is called. I can not figure out how it could cause issues howeer. I mean to some degree certainly, since it is technically a from of Multitasking (by re-entering the Event Queue), but for this code it should not mater.

Comment: A little course about the Designer: In WindowsForms, each form is at least 2 parts in 2 .cs files. One part the designer works on. It's code is executed with `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor. The other part is what you showed us here, the part you worked on. Without seeing the Designer part, we can not say anything for sure. But the events not being registered with the Buttons is the most likely cause.

Comment: FYI, most Windows Forms example codes do not includ the designer side. Even I will usually omit it. Most programmers do not need an explanation what the designer side should look like with stuff like "txtOutput.Text" in this part of the file. And the designer tends to be incredibly verbose about it's stuff, only assigning one value per line even if it could do all 4 coordiates at the same time.

Comment: @TaW I created the button events myself by double clicking them. However I did cut and past the methods from the top to the bottom, would that cause issues?

Comment: No, that should not be a problem, unless you went down too far and left the form class scope. But if they didn't work as intended, maybe the names didn't match? If you have an event code already before you double clcick the button etc the created event will be named e.g. btn_click_1. Always watch out for that!

Comment: Christopher: [I can not figure out how it could cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821086/why-does-my-array-shuffling-function-only-work-when-the-code-is-stepped-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, most likely your events are not hooked up to your buttons.  You can do this several ways; typically it's done in the designer.

To know for sure if this is the cause, try this:

```
public Form1() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CalcButton.Click += CalcButton_Click;
}
```

Note that this assumes your button is named "CalcButton".  You can see whether that's true in the designer as well.

If that works, you need to do the same with the rest of your buttons either the same way or by selecting the method in the designer for the button.

Comment: I believe I found the part of the cause, I had a curly bracket closing the public partial class Form1 : Form before the end of the code. Now the exit button works but the calculate and clear buttons do not.

Comment: I was able to recreate the event handlers for each and the program seems to be working as intended. Thanks for your input.